# get the Aura:id from event

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can i get the aura:id dynamically from event attribute, the below example i was trying to get the aura:id to get the value, else you can think as aura:id might be some field APIname so i can pass this field name and value to controller to store the value dynamically.

code 
component:

```
<aura:component controller = "LC_AutoSave" implements="force:appHostable" >
    <form>
        <ui:inputtext  value = ""  aura:id ="testtext"  blur = "{!c.autoSave}"/>
        <ui:inputtext value = "" aura:id ="testtext1"  blur = "{!c.autoSave}"/>
        <ui:inputtext value = "" aura:id ="testtext2"  blur = "{!c.autoSave}"/>

   </form>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    autoSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        var a = event.getSource();
        console.log('Test'+a.get("v.aura:Id"));
        helper.autoSavehelper(component,event);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just call `component.getLocalId()`

So it'd be:

```
var a = event.getSource();
var id = a.getLocalId();
```

> To find the local ID for a component in JavaScript, use cmp.getLocalId().

Source [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm?search_text=globalid):

Comment: It works to me ,Thanks, also please suggest how could i find these methods information, i searched aura framework documentation didn't find it.

Comment: That's a tricky one. Sometimes you just need to know what to search for. That will come with experience. I'll update the question with the link.

Comment: This is great however, i notice that it works for me as a static value, eg: id="tehidval" however, if i use it like id="{!v.attribute}" becuase this is dynamic generated by an action, then it will display  {!v.attribute}, I am wondering if this is possible?

Comment: hmm, it should work dynamically - because this is how you specify a unique id for the component - ie `id="{!GlobalId + 'some_val'}"` ... so replacing that with an attribute I would have thought would work.